# Add two numbers in django

Tags: python, django

Edited :

I'm new to django and i need to add two numbers x and y .

The x and y are inputs from user.

Here is my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import InputForm

def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        # If the form has been submitted...
     form = InputForm(request.POST)     # A form bound to the POST data
     if form.is_valid():                # All validation rules pass
        cd = form.cleaned_data     # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        input1 = cd['x']
        input2 = cd['y']
        output = input1 + input2
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request,'/thanks/')# Redirect to new url
   else:
        form = InputForm()   # An unbound form


   return render(request, 'scraper/base.html', {'form': form })     


def thanks(request,output):
return render(request, 'scraper/base.html', output)
```

Here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms

class InputForm(forms.Form):
     x = forms.IntegerField(label='Value of x')
     y = forms.IntegerField(label='Value of y')
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.add, name='add'),
url(r'^/', views.thanks , name='thanks'),
]
```

here is output.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Thanks</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Thanks</h1>
  <h1> Output = {{output}} </h1>
  </body>
  </html>
```

User inputs the x and y values then click add button the output should be displayed in a new page like output.html so how to do that ?

I know there are some errors in views.py i'm learning django. Please point it out and tell me the correct way to implement this

I'm struggling for 5 hours.

Comment: How does your urls.py look like? According to the error message there's something wrong with it

Comment: Please share your urls.py

Comment: Try: `HttpResponse('Result: {}'.format(output))` instead of `HttpResponseRedirect(...)`

Comment: Adding two numbers isn't your real issue at all, What is the *exact* problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: @Sayse I want to learn how to get two input from a form and add them and display it in a separate output page.

Comment: @utkbansal I've added the urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the redirect incorrectly, you can't send parameter in `HttpResponseRedirect`, check the modification here and take look in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) for more explanation:

**views.py**

```py
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        # If the form has been submitted...
     form = InputForm(request.POST)     # A form bound to the POST data
     if form.is_valid():                # All validation rules pass
        cd = form.cleaned_data     # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        input1 = cd['x']
        input2 = cd['y']
        output = input1 + input2
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/{output}/'.format(output=output)) # Redirect to new url
   else:
        form = InputForm()   # An unbound form
   return render(request, 'scraper/base.html', {'form': form })
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^thanks/(?P<output>\d+)/$', thanks),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sessions to store the output and then retrieve it in the next view. The session framework lets you store and retrieve arbitrary data on a per-site-visitor basis.

Edit your views.py as follows -

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = InputForm(request.POST)     
        if form.is_valid():                
            cd = form.cleaned_data     
            input1 = cd['x']
            input2 = cd['y']
            output = input1 + input2
            # Save the result in the session
            request.session['output'] = output
            return  HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = InputForm() 
    return render(request, 'scraper/base.html', {'form': form })  


def thanks(request):
    # Get the result from the session
    output = request.session.pop('output', None)
    return render(request, 'scraper/output.html', {'output':output})
```

And you urls.py should be -

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.add, name='add'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks , name='thanks'),
]
```

Comment: You have an indentation error on the last line of the `thanks` function.

Comment: @SanjayOrtiz share your thanks.html template too. Seems like an error there.

Comment: oh sorry, share output.html

Comment: Please check thee last line of the add function. ISit same in your code as in mine?

Comment: Bro, thank you so much. I restarted the server and it worked like charm. You made my day. I'm interested in learning more about sessions please point out some place to learn maybe a website .

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/ This would be  great place